# Jade Unexpected block Error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

*NOTE: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975302/warning-unexpected-block-scripts-jade) question, but not the same.*

I have an expressjs node website (WIP), but I keep getting the follwoing error:

```
Warning: Unexpected block "head"  on line 3 of \src\dynamic\views\index.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
Warning: Unexpected block "body"  on line 5 of \src\dynamic\views\index.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
```

My `src\dynamic\views\index.jade`:

```
extends _includes/head/head
block head
   title Skool - On Our Way!
block body
   extends _includes/navbars/topNav
```

The `_includes/navbars/topNav.jade` file is just a basic jade file depicting a simple bootstrap navbar, so I will omit it.

`_includes/head/head`:

```
doctype html
html
   head
      link(rel="styleSheet" href="css/main.css")
      script(src="js/app.js")
      block head

   body
      block body
```

Now when I visit `localhost:3000`, I am greeted with my compiled jade file, except the `<head>` element is empty, so there are no css links! Checking the console log I see the previously mentioned error/warning.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that you should only use **extends** once in your view. Use **include** for topNav

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know there was an include statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to [**@Molda**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda) for pointing me in the right direction. (S)he said:

> I think that you should only use **extends** once in your view. Use **include** for topNav.

So as soon as I replaced that one extends it worked, and my `<head>` element was no longer empty.

Now I cannot find anything that documents the "you can only use `extends` once" rule, but as far as I can gather only the last extends is used.